# Как делать преобразование в разметке xaml в реальном времени?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

У меня есть Page.Resources в котором, предположим, расписана размеры элементов кнопки. Как мне сделать чтобы при растягивании и сжатии окна приложения пропорции кнопки менялись так же одновременно. Например, иконка кнопки всегда была 1/4 ширины окна прилоги.

```
<Style x:Key="Autorize_Button" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundTransparentBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderThemeThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,4,8,4"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    <Rectangle Name="Line" Height="1.5" Width="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" Fill="White" Opacity="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Вот ресурсы кнопки, необходимо изменять ширину прямоугольника с названием Line (1/3 ширины окна)

Comment: Привязка через конвертер?

Comment: @VladD можно ссылочку с примером?)

Comment: Ну, если вы дадите код кнопки с иконкой, попробую составить пример.

Comment: @VladD добавил код в вопрос

Comment: Размещаете кнопку в ячейке Grid и указываете Width & Height в Auto, задаете нужные Margin, MinWidth и MinHeight. И теперь при изменении размеров страницы у вас будет изменятся размер кнопки.

Comment: @Bulson я попробовал сделать так, какой я ставлю минимальный размер такой и будет, он не растягивается в дальнейшем...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

К сожалению, `ActualWidth` в UWP, в отличие от WPF, является вычисляемым свойством, и не отправляет сообщений о своём изменении. Поэтому нам придётся сделать достаточно сложное решение.

Во-первых, нам нужно `DependencyProperty`, которое будет давать значение текущей ширины. В классе страницы (пусть он называется `MainPage`) объявляем:

```
public double ComputedActualWidth
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(ComputedActualWidthProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ComputedActualWidthProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ComputedActualWidthProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ComputedActualWidth", typeof(double), typeof(MainPage),
                                new PropertyMetadata(0.0));
```

и в конструкторе

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SizeChanged += (o, args) => ComputedActualWidth = ActualWidth;
    ComputedActualWidth = ActualWidth;
}
```

Теперь можно класть привязку:

```
<Rectangle Name="Line" Height="1.5"
           Width="{Binding ComputedActualWidth,
                           ElementName=Root,
                           Converter={StaticResource OneFourthConverter}}"
           ... />
```

Конвертер объявляете как

```
class OneFourthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object p, string language) =>
        (double)value / 4;

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object p, string language) =>
        (double)value * 4;
}
```

и кладёте в доступные ресурсы:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:OneFourthConverter x:Key="OneFourthConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

Странице даёте имя `Root`.

---

Выдержка из рабочего кода:

```
<Page
    x:Class="Test.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Test"
    xmlns:i="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
    xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
    xmlns:media="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Media"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Name="Root">
    <Page.Resources>
        <local:OneFourthConverter x:Key="OneFourthConverter"/>
        <Style x:Key="Autorize_Button" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundTransparentBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderThemeThickness}"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,4,8,4"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
            <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            <Rectangle Name="Line" Height="15"
                                       Width="{Binding ComputedActualWidth,
                                                       ElementName=Root,
                                                       Converter={StaticResource OneFourthConverter},
                                                       Mode=OneWay}"
                                       Fill="Red" Opacity="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>
    <Grid Background="Gray">
        <Button Style="{StaticResource Autorize_Button}" Height="30" Width="300"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Я поменял Opacity на 1, чтобы линия была видна.

Comment: "Не удалось найти свойство "AncestorType" в типе "RelativeSource"" :*(

Comment: @Denisok: Окей, это была попытка для WPF, поправил, пробуйте теперь.

Comment: Можно глупый вопрос?) Как дать имя странице?)

Comment: @Denisok: `<Page Name="Root" ...`. Но этот вариант тоже не работает, т. к. ActualWidth не даёт привязаться как надо. Сейчас подыщу ещё вариант.

Comment: @Denisok: Вот так вроде лучше, пробуйте ещё раз

Comment: А конвертер можно создать в  этом же MainPage?

Comment: @Denisok: Можно, но не в самом классе, а вне него.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47239/discussion-between-denisok-and-vladd).